# How do I get the react-bootstrap progress bar to display in my React application

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I need help getting my progress bar from react-bootstrap to display. I have installed both bootstrap and react-bootstrap from yarn and I imported both files and the component into my react app. Somehow it still doesn't work for me. Any suggestions

Dashboard.js

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import {Container,Row,Col, ProgressBar} from 'react-bootstrap'
import './table.css';
function Dashboard(props) {

  return (

    <div>
   <ProgressBar now={60}/>
</div>


  );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Its work for me, without `table.css`, what's inside `table.css`?

Answer (score 0):

try `Progress` instead of `ProgressBar`:

```
        <div>
          <Progress value={60} />
        </div>
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactstrap-smhra4)

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with the way that you are importing the bootstrap CSS file.

The documentation mentions to import it like this:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

The following line can be included in your `src/index.js` or `App.js` file

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your webpack.config file

```
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  }
  ...
```